# How to toggle custom selection in IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Ok, i confess, i don't know how it got this way.

[image]

How can i toggle the world back to normal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in column selection mode; to adjust go to `Edit > Column Selection Mode`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have column selection mode enabled.  To disable it, go to Edit > Column Selection Mode and disable it.